# Error: cannot use an address to initialize a field of a packed struct (#pragma pack)

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, solaris

I'm trying to use solaris studio for Linux on Ubuntu 10.10.

When I tried building following code,
    const char * names [] = { "Apple", "Orange", "Mango"};

I'm getting following error message,
"cannot use an address to initialize a field of a packed struct (#pragma pack)"

I'm not using #pragma pack(), I even tried with #pragma pack(0) to make it default and also tried with #pragma align 64 ( names)

Still I get the same error.
What is the reason.
Thanks

Comment: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=dc84943191e06dffffffffdf200f5210dd319?bug_id=6954910

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using, I got no error with the following program and Solaris Studio 12.2 / Sun C 5.11 on Linux:

```
$ cat tst.c
int main(void)
{
    const char *names[] = {"Apple", "Orange", "Mango"};
} 
$ cc tst.c
$ echo $?
0
$ cc -V
cc: Sun C 5.11 Linux_i386 2010/08/13
usage: cc [ options ] files.  Use 'cc -flags' for details
$
```

Comment: Using 12.3 latest version. Below is list of CC options used while building the file.

Comment: When I tried this in a new application it did work but I'm trying to use solaris studio on a bigger project in which this happened. Any other reason that could be making names[] as packed struct? Originally the project uses gcc and with gcc there is no problem as such.